# Как в xargs пометить переменные

Tags: linux

Я имею дело с двумя строками, в каждой по одному аругменту. Которые хочу представить в одну строку и подставить эти аргументы в разные места.

Например я вижу в терминале:

```
ХХХ
YYY
```

Хочу чтоб стало так.

```
Odin XXX Dva YYY
```

С помощью xargs пробовал так:

```
xargs -I{} -n2 -L2 echo "Odin {} Dva {}"
```

Но получаю:

```
Odin {} Dva {} XXX YYY
```

Как пометить аргументы XXX и YYY, чтобы подставить в нужное место в команде.

Answer (score 1):

В `xargs` -- никак. Используйте `parallel`:

```
$ parallel -N2 echo Odin {1} Dva {2} << EOF
> XXX
> YYY
> EOF
Odin XXX Dva YYY
```

Answer (score 0):

немного «магии» с обычно присутствующими по умолчанию даже в самой «спартанской» инсталляции программами:

```
$ echo -e 'xxx\nyyy' | nl -s '=' -w 1 | sed 's/^/v/;$s/$/\necho odin $v1 dva $v2/' | sh
odin xxx dva yyy
```

---

«разоблачения».

1. нумеруем строки с помощью программы *nl*:

   ```
   $ echo -e 'xxx\nyyy' | nl -s '=' -w 1
   1=xxx
   2=yyy
   ```

   `-s '='` — между номером строки и самой строкой вставить символ <kbd>=</kbd>.
   `-w 1` — длина номеров.
2. команды для программы *sed*:

   1. `s/^/v/` — в начале строки добавить символ <kbd>v</kbd>, её результат:

      ```
      v1=xxx
      v2=yyy
      ```
   2. `$s/$/\necho odin $v1 dva $v2/` — первый из <kbd>$</kbd> (перед командой `s`) — это адрес. означает «последняя строка». в её конец вставляем строку `\necho odin $v1 dva $v2`, где `\n` — это символ перевода строки. текущий результат — уже три строки:

      ```
      $ echo -e 'xxx\nyyy' | nl -s '=' -w 1 | sed 's/^/v/;$s/$/\necho odin $v1 dva $v2/'
      v1=xxx
      v2=yyy
      echo odin $v1 dva $v2
      ```
3. осталось исполнить эти три строки как скрипт оболочки, передав по «конвейеру» (<kbd>|</kbd>) любой из *posix*-совместимых оболочек (например, *sh*):

   ```
   $ echo -e 'xxx\nyyy' | nl -s '=' -w 1 | sed 's/^/v/;$s/$/\necho odin $v1 dva $v2/' | sh
   odin xxx dva yyy
   ```